# Short movie about getting faster and aging faster

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, tv

I watched this short movie on TV in the '90 but cannot recall the title. I am almost sure this was from "The Outer Limits" but could not find any correspondence.

The story is about a young man (a fighter?) who meets an old man (an Asian?) who gives him a potion? formula? which enables him to be faster than usual.

He then starts to win his fights (I think) - as he sees the movements of other people as very slow (this is similar to how [The Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(Barry_Allen)) sees other people when moving fast).

He then realizes that something is wrong with him, goes to see the man who gave him the potion, to realize that that old man is actually young (from his ID if I remember correctly). Getting faster also means that one ages faster.

If there was a moral stance at the end of the movie (as it is the case with The Outer Limits), I cannot remember what it was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does indeed sound like an episode of the Outer Limits (1995) version, ["In The Zone."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Zone_(The_Outer_Limits))

From the Wikipedia description:

> With its deadly lasers and hand-to-hand battles, 'The Octal' is a combat sport for a new generation of athletes — but Tanner Brooks is no longer a young man. Although he's promised his wife Jessica that this will be his final tournament, Tanner is desperate to go out a winner. Dr. Michael Chen has a way to make that happen. Through an experimental treatment that taps the power of the human nervous system, Chen accelerates Tanner's reflexes and perceptions. To Tanner, everything in the Octal begins to move in slow motion ... and Tanner quickly becomes unbeatable. However, there are side effects: Jessica notices that Tanner is tired, haggard and his hair is going gray.

And

> A cured but aged Tanner and Jessica look at the "explanation" Dr. Chen left to them - his driver's license, which shows that he should have been only thirty years old. They realize he had tested the procedure on himself, causing his body to speed up and age faster.

Hit most of the points you mentioned, the athlete, the slow motion, the aging side effects, the Asian doctor (played by Pat Morita) and the revelation at the end that the doctor really wasn't old, he tested the treatment on himself first.

The moral lesson, or at least the closing narration was:

> For the human race life is a ceaseless competition for power, for fame, even love. But when the desire for victory is reduced to winning at any cost, then we can only guarantee our defeat.

Comment: This is exactly this, thank you. I scrolled the episodes of this series I like so much (bring wonderful memories) but missed that episode. Thanks! I now remember that there was a woman involved as well (his wife)